# How can I make gitweb ignore whitespace changes?

Tags: git, diff, whitespace, git-commit, gitweb

Is there a url parameter I can pass into gitweb (or anything else I can do) to tell it not to show me whitespace changes?

Backstory:
I have a file-generating process that creates hundreds of files that it then programatically checks into git.  Recently I made some minor changes to this process, which resulted in a bunch of whitespace being removed from every file that it generates, and some non-whitespace changes being made to just a few files that it generates.  I am trying to use gitweb to verify that my non-whitespace changes are in these files, but it's really hard to do because of all the whitespace changes I have to sift through before I see any of the real changes.  I know if I were doing a git diff from the command line I could just pass it the -w parameter, but I am really just trying to use gitweb for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is supported after taking quick glance at the source on [github](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.perl) mirror.

```
our @diff_opts = ('-M'); # taken from git_commit
```

You could post a feature request to the git mailing list to perhaps make this configurable via `gitweb.conf`, some UI element, or url parameter. If you are feeling keen, fork it ;)

Github uses a url parameter if your looking for ideas:

`Add ?w=1 to the URL to see the diff with whitespace ignored.`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but for those arriving here from a Google search: the `@diff_opts` config parameter in /etc/gitweb.conf can be used for this. The text in the config file implies that `@diff_opts` is only there to support `git-diff-tree`'s file copy and rename detection, but actually you can put in any supported git diff option you like.  So to suppress whitespace differences, you could use

```
@diff_opts = ('-b');
```

which works well for me. I realise it's not a URL parameter, so not directly answering this question, but maybe useful to others.